# Insert parent records and update linked children

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is such a simple problem, but I cannot figure out the syntax to do this. I'm doing some data migration, and I have some existing records in a table that I want to link to a brand new parent table.

Let's say I have two tables:

```
declare @Parent table
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    DummyField int
)

declare @Child table
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    ParentID int, -- assume this is a new column, all nulls
    DummyField int
)
```

For each existing Child record, insert a new parent record and update Child to link to it.

That's it. It's so simple, but I can't figure it out without using a cursor.

Comment: So simple and yet such a vague question. Is there an identity or do you provide the value for ID? Seems a bit strange to have a parent child relation ship where the child comes first. Perhaps you could expand on this a little bit and give use more details. Maybe using OUTPUT or MERGE...but it is so hard to tell what you are trying to do here.

Comment: The ID columns of both tables are identity columns, so those values are automatic. And this is for data migration, which is why the child records already exist without the parents.

Comment: Step1) Use a table variable that has ID and ParentID for columns, fill it with IDs from Child and row_number() for ParentID. Step2) Fill ParentID from table variable into Parent table. Step3) Join Child table to table variable on ID and update ParentID. Step4) Netflix and Chill.

Comment: Some records to new parent table.  You don't get to just link some records.

Answer (score 1):

Seudo SQL logic seems to be pretty simple ...

```
insert in to parent.

update childern 
set ParentID = select @@IDENTITY
where ParentID = @previousParentId
```

unless I missed something here?

Comment: That works for a single record, but I'm trying to process multiple records at once without resorting to a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

relation betwwen child and parent is missing

you hv to use output clause to achive so,

try like this,

```
declare @output table (parentid int)
insert into parent (parentid)
output inserted.parentid into @output
-- values


update c 
set ParentID = o.parentid
from children c
inner join @output o on c.parentid=o.parentid
```

Comment: Aren't you joining on c.parentid before it's set?

Comment: @BradDaBug,with what detail you hv provided and wht i understood.Say I hv convert War script into bulk insert/update